# Unity5 Button on Click don't work

Tags: javascript, button, unityscript, unity-game-engine

[If you click here you can see there is no function there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqyOw.png) Unity Buildt in a component where you can choose your script and from it any function. I write this script and when i want to choose the function it's write "no function". Pls help me!

```
 #pragma strict

    function QuitGamne() {
        Debug.Log ("Game is exiting....");
        Application.Quit ();
    }

    function StartGame() {
        Application.LoadLevel ("level1");
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a step by step of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I try to do a script for a button to start my game and close  it. I'm using Unity 5.3. I've done buttons graphics'. I made the scripts(See above). And i can't use them at the buttons. I try to use "On Click ()" option in "Button (Script)" component. I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your functions are private. Make them public.

```
#pragma strict
public function QuitGamne() {
    Debug.Log ("Game is exiting....");
    Application.Quit ();
}

public function StartGame() {
    Application.LoadLevel ("level1");
}
```

Comment: Don't work :/ I add an image, i hope it's easier to unerstand.

Comment: Choose MonoScript and select your public function.

Comment: Under MonoScrip only "string name".

Comment: I see, then double check if the GameObject has the script you want and is assigned to OnClick panel of button. You should see the name of your script whan you try to select the function for onClick. If you still not see it my quess is that updating unity will help (BTW looks like quite old Unity, what version it is?).

Comment: Unity 5.3.3f1 (64-bit)